# Parametrize HTML Search Box to Query API with GET

Tags: html, search, get

I have an API that returns search results as `JSON` given search input and an API key.

I would like to create a search box that submits keywords to the API and which returns results.

I am working with this code template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Search Box Example 1</title>
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" />
<!-- CSS styles for standard search box -->
<style type="text/css">
    #tfheader{
        background-color:#c3dfef;
    }
    #tfnewsearch{
        float:right;
        padding:20px;
    }
    .tftextinput{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 15px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
        border:1px solid #0076a3; border-right:0px;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
    }
    .tfbutton {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 15px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        border: solid 1px #0076a3; border-right:0px;
        background: #0095cd;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#00adee), to(#0078a5));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00adee,  #0078a5);
        border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
    }
    .tfbutton:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #007ead;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0095cc), to(#00678e));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0095cc,  #00678e);
    }
    /* Fixes submit button height problem in Firefox */
    .tfbutton::-moz-focus-inner {
      border: 0;
    }
    .tfclear{
        clear:both;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- HTML for SEARCH BAR -->
    <div id="tfheader">
        <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get" action="http://www.google.com">
                <input type="text" class="tftextinput" name="q" size="21" maxlength="120"><input type="submit" value="search" class="tfbutton">
        </form>
    <div class="tfclear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the `R` language (which I know a lot better than HTML) I can sucessfully submit a query and capture the results with the following line:

```
test <- GET(url="https://api.domain.com/store/data/unique_indentifier/_query?input/search_query=BLACK%20BOX&_user_unique_indentifier&_apikey=xxxxxx/MZgI01RVu+fI6x/cd+riqIpg==")
```

I'm unclear however on how to bridge the gap between the the two. Meaning, I don't know how to take my example non-parametrized GET query from R and adapt it for the nicely parametrized HTML Google search example.

In the query above I chose "BLACK BOX" as arbitrary search terms. Real queries could be 1 or more words, upper or lower case.

Comment: But, your example `GET` is parameterized. Or, do you mean you don't know how to create dynamic parameters?

Comment: @hrmstr in the example `GET` is parameterized for a Google search, but if I just substitute in the URL of my API it will not work because (a) it doesn't address the use of an API key and (b) the URL string needed for my API is different from what Google apparently needs, as you can see in the example I gave in R

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's the "build a list of parameters", something like this, perhaps. I'll use the httpbin.org `get` service which will spit back what is posted in JSON:

```
library(httr)

pg <- GET("http://httpbin.org/get",
          query=list(search="word1 word2 word3",
                     someoption="param2",
                     anotheroption="param3"), verbose())

## -> GET /get?search=word1%20word2%20word3&someoption=param2&anotheroption=param3 HTTP/1.1
## -> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0 Rcurl/1.95.4.3 httr/0.5
## -> Host: httpbin.org
## -> Accept-Encoding: gzip
## -> accept: application/json, text/xml, */*
## -> 
## <- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
## <- Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
## <- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
## <- Content-Type: application/json
## <- Date: Wed, 15 Oct 2014 21:39:15 GMT
## <- Server: gunicorn/18.0
## <- Content-Length: 522
## <- Connection: keep-alive
## <- 

ret <- content(pg, as="parsed")

str(ret)

## List of 4
##  $ args   :List of 3
##   ..$ anotheroption: chr "param3"
##   ..$ search       : chr "word1 word2 word3"
##   ..$ someoption   : chr "param2"
##  $ headers:List of 6
##   ..$ Accept         : chr "application/json, text/xml, */*"
##   ..$ Accept-Encoding: chr "gzip"
##   ..$ Connection     : chr "close"
##   ..$ Host           : chr "httpbin.org"
##   ..$ User-Agent     : chr "curl/7.30.0 Rcurl/1.95.4.3 httr/0.5"
##   ..$ X-Request-Id   : chr "f2d9f3d9-320c-4a00-99a5-b89adc64ad26"
##  $ origin : chr "132.177.197.105"
##  $ url    : chr "http://httpbin.org/get?search=word1 word2 word3&someoption=param2&anotheroption=param3"
```

Just build a list of parameters and pass it in to `GET`.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not trying to do this in R because I'm trying to make a website with a search box. I was showing the GET() example in R because I'm more familiar with R so I knew how to do GET() there but I'm trying to make that HTML search box work with the information from my GET() query in R. I just deleted the R tag, that was probably misleading.